# Angular callHooks not triggered when refresh page

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

i had problem when i use **F5 button or directive call url from address bar** ngOnInit not called properly.. I'm using debugger to see what happen, and the problem is callHook not triggered after ngOnInit..

I'm using Angular 9.1.2

This is my ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('fired OnInit');
    
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType : 'full_numbers',
      pageLength : 10
    };
    this.getCurrentUser();
    this.initializeList();
    this.resetFormData();
  }
```

and i'm using Ngx-Soap for call database, here's my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Client, ISoapMethodResponse, NgxSoapService } from 'ngx-soap';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Document } from '../_models/document.model';
import { User } from '../_models/user.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeneralService {
  client : Client;
  xmlResponse : string;
  jsonResponse : string;
  resultLabel : string;

  constructor(
    private soap : NgxSoapService
  ) {
    this.soap.createClient(environment.wsURL).then(client=>{
      client.addSoapHeader({
        'tns:ModuleCredential':{
          'tns:ModuleAppName':'xxxx',
          'tns:ModuleUserName':'xxxx',
          'tns:ModulePassword':'xxxx'
        }  
      });
      client.addHttpHeader(
        'Content-Type','text/xml; charset=utf-8'
      );
      this.client = client;
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log('SoapError',err))
   }

  Login(formData : User) : Observable<ISoapMethodResponse>{
    const body = {
      data : formData
    };    
    return this.client.call('Login',body)
  }

  GetCategoryList():Observable<ISoapMethodResponse>{
    const body ={
      data:null
    };
    return this.client.call('GetCategoryList',body);
  }
```

[this is my image from Debugger, and those 3 yellow not called after ngOnInit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u457.png)

[this is my console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAO9y.png)

Comment: It sounds like `ngOnInit()` is firing, but how what isn't working that should happen in those `callHook`s?

Comment: ```callHooks``` is skipped after ```ngOnInit()``` is firing, so ```refreshView``` will do ```leaveView()``` because ```callHooks``` not detected any changes

Comment: It sounds like there's potentially something weird with the project/components. If you had a working example in stackblitz it would be easier to suss out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for awhile and test everything, so the answer is back to NgxSoap, the constructor of service not triggered and cause this error..
Still looking why this constructor not triggered at NgxSoap github..
Thanks all..

Comment: maybe it was solved in this updated ngx-soap package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap-next and if not, feel free to contribute

Answer (score 0):

Show what error the Chrome DevTools console gives you.

Comment: i updated my question, add console result

Comment: Seems to be an angular-cli bug, check out this issue on GitHub:: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14779

Comment: I also think it's a general bug, but more information is needed about your code and other details.

Comment: There are lifecycles in Angular that you can consider: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks